# Preventing Jade from adding an assignment clause in an HTML element

Tags: javascript, pug, angular

I want to define a local variable in an input tag for an Angular 2 application:

```
input(#sometext)
button((click)="addTechnology(sometext.value)") Add
```

The output that I am expecting is:

```
<input #sometext/>
<button (click)="addTechnology(sometext.value)">Add</button>
```

However the real output is (notice the additional `="#sometext"`):

```
<input #sometext="#sometext"/>
<button (click)="addTechnology(sometext.value)">Add</button>
```

This way, Angular 2 throws the following error, very likely due to that `="#sometext"`:

```
Cannot find directive with exportAs = '#sometext'

Error: Cannot find directive with exportAs = '#sometext'
    at new BaseException (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.28/angular2.dev.js:7248:25)
    at _findDirectiveIndexByExportAs (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.28/angular2.dev.js:12454:13)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.28/angular2.dev.js:12435:22
    at Map.forEach (native)
    at Function.execute.MapWrapper.forEach (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.28/angular2.dev.js:7614:15)
    at createDirectiveVariableBindings (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.28/angular2.dev.js:12434:16)
    at _createProtoElementInjector (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.28/angular2.dev.js:12414:39)
    at _createElementBinders (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.28/angular2.dev.js:12391:34)
    at _createAppProtoView (https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.28/angular2.dev.js:12331:5)
    at https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.28/angular2.dev.js:12641:32
```

Do you know any way of preventing Jade from completing the attribute with the additional `="#sometext"`?

Comment: Probably it's the `#`

Comment: According to the doc https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/guide/user-input.html that's the way to define a variable, isn't it?

Comment: The problem is the uppercase. The browser converts it to lowercase before angular compiles and there's nothing they can do about it. Change it to `#sometext`. See this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1447

Comment: Same error with #sometext :-(

Comment: I've updated the question with the actual code. I hadn't realized that my template Engine, Jade, generates the markup in a differente way than I was expecting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the end it was as simple as using `doctype html` at the beginning of the Jade template. I had it in the main layout but it seems that the included files also need it.